# SendMessage when Colliding?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my character work with an asset. My character has punching animations. I want when it punches an object, it breaks.

I've tried OnCollisionEnter and OnTriggerEnter. But original script for destroying objects using "OnMouseDown" and Raycasts.

```
        if(punched){
            RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay (new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.0f));
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)){
            ////    SEND A MESSAGE DAMAGING THE OBJECT HIT
                hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("Damage", 1f, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);          
            }
        }
    }
```

I want this to work when my collider collides with an object, instead of raycast system. So pretty much when my assigned collider on my player touch the object that needs to break. Please help, I'm confused :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out different things, I was able to accomplish what I wanted by using **OnTriggerEnter** instead. And it worked like a charm. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're over thinking it.
Why not just put a script on the game object that detects the collision?

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) 
{
          if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Fist"))
              Debug.Log ("I have broken");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your script the variant would be:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collider) 
{
      collider.gameObject.SendMessage("Damage", 1f, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
}
```

Al dough u shouldn't be using SendMessage, but hey.

Comment: That did not work for me :/ I've added a box collider to an object and this script. It doesn't do anything.